# Regular expression no match when followed by character

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture groups in a text that only match when the match is not followed by a specific character, in this case the opening parentheses "(" to indicate the start of a 'function/method' rather than a 'property'.

This seems pretty straightforward so I tried:

```php
TEXT

$this->willMatch but $this->willNot()

RESULT

RegExp pattern: \$this->[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+(?<!\()
Expected: $this->willMatch
Actual: $this->willMatch, $this->willNot

RegExp pattern: \$this->[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+[^\(]
Expected: $this->willMatch
Actual: $this->willMatch, $this->willNot

RegExp pattern: \$this->[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?!\()
Expected: $this->willMatch
Actual: $this->willMatch, $this->willNo
```

My intuition says i need to add ^ and $ but that wont work for multiple occurrences in a text.

Curious to meet the RegExp wizard that can solve this!

Comment: This question is [currently under discussion on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405720/3773011).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `(?<!\()` will always be true as the character class does not match a `(`

Note that you don't have to escape the `\_`

You can use a word boundary after the character class to prevent backtracking, and turn the negative lookbehind into a negative lookahead `(?!\()` to assert not `(` directly to the right.

```
\$this->[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\b(?!\()
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RE2VR5/1/)

Answer (score 8):

[Answer from The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66063364/548225) definitely works and it is well explained as well.

As an alternative to using word boundary one can use [**possessive quantifier**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) i.e. `++` to turn off backtracking thus improving efficiency further.

```sh
\$this->\w++(?!\()
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FbDdTf/1/)

Please note use of `\w` instead of equivalent `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` here.

Like a greedy quantifier, a possessive quantifier repeats the token as many times as possible. Unlike a greedy quantifier, it does not give up matches as the engine backtracks.

Comment: It looks like only PCRE has this feature. It does not work on Python.

Comment: Yes that's right. You will need to use `\b` option for python

Comment: @AlexReinking The stock `re` regular expression engine for Python does not support possessive quantifiers. However, Python has other regular expression implementations with expanded syntax. For example, on SmokeDetector we use the [`regex` package](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), which does support possessive quantifiers.